# I'm getting an error when pulling data into the table Angular Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using ngrx. I see the data is coming but I can't show it in the table I created selector reducer and action files. IDE did not give an error, but my data is still not reflected in the table.

> How can i resolve this problem. can you suggest a solution

My Selector File:

```
const selectStatisticsState = createFeatureSelector<State>(statisticsFeatureKey);

export const selectStatistics = createSelector(
    selectStatisticsState,
    ((statistic): Statistics => statistic)
);

export const selectAllStatistics= createSelector(selectStatisticsState, (statistics: Statistics) => statistics.allStatistics);
```

My Reducer File:

```
export const statisticsFeatureKey = 'statistics';
export interface State extends Statistics {
  
}

export const initialState: State = {
  userCount: 0,
  messageCount: 0,
  messageWithCommentCount: 0,
  messageWithoutCommentCount: 0,
  allStatistics: []
};

export const statisticReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(loadStatisticsSuccess, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    ...action.statistics
}))

);
```

My Service File:

```
getStatistics(): Observable<Statistics> {
    return this.apiService.get(this.baseUrl, 'statistics');
}
```

Statistics Class:

```
   export interface Statistics {
        userCount: number;
        messageCount: number;
        messageWithCommentCount: number;
        messageWithoutCommentCount: number;
        allStatistics: UserStatistics[];
        myStatistics?: UserStatistics;
    }
    
    export interface UserStatistics {
        userId: string;
        ratingCount: number;
        ratingAverage: number;
        commentCount: number;
    }
```

My Table .ts File

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-leaderboard',
  templateUrl: './leaderboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leaderboard.component.scss']
})
export class LeaderboardComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['userId', 'commentCount', 'ratingAverage'];
  statistics$ = this.store.select(selectAllStatistics);

  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }
  
}
```

HTML File:

```
    <div class="leaderboard-table-wrapper">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="statistics$ | async">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Yorumcu Adı</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.userId}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="commentCount">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Yorumladığı Sayı</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.commentCount} </td>
    </ng-container>

  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ratingAverage">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Değerlendirme Puanı</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ratingAverage}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"
                 style="width: 80vw;">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

My Data picture.
[image]

Table Null Problem Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics is not an array, dataSource expects an array. So if you had an array of Statistics it will work.

Edit:

After seeing the error message you have, your selector should look like so:

```
export const selectAllStatistics= createSelector(selectStatisticsState, (statistics: Statistics) => statistics.allStatistics);
```

Notice how the inner arrow function is different, I have it as `(statistics: Statistics)` whereas you have it as `(statistic): Statistics`. Your version is incorrect since you are telling the code that you expect it to return a `Statistics` object instead of a UserStatistics by having the `:` be outside of your Parenthesis.

If you include it within the parenthesis, then what you are telling typescript then is "For the object that is returned from my `selectStatisticsState` it will be of type `Statistics`

Further reading: https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: Is there a way to show the data other than datasource?

Comment: Do you need it to be in a table? The whole point of mat table is to help abstract away creating a table for multiple rows of data. You can also manually create a table yourself, break it into something else, or just create a local variable that is an array. ex: statisticsArray = [ [], ...statistics]. Keep in mind you would need to subscribe and get the statistics object and assign it to something else since it can't be an async pipe

Comment: I am change my selector function but ı can not see any data in my table can you check again. I dont understand why my data didnt show

Comment: can you edit your question with the newest selector function you made?

Comment: Another thing, your displayed columns are for UserStatistics, not Statistics. Two separate objects. Assuming you want to actually target UserStatistics. Make statistics$ return a regular Statistics object, not an array, then make your html be like so [dataSource]="(statistics$ | async).allStatistics"

Comment: export const selectAllStatistics = createSelector(
    selectStatisticsState,
    ((statistic): UserStatistics[] => statistic.allStatistics)
);

Comment: my selector file as i posted above, In the last case, I don't get an error in the code line, but I still can't see the data.    [dataSource]="(statistics$ | async).allStatistics" didn't work

Comment: Are you sure that selector works? Because usually a selector is using a slice of the state. So you would have your state, and that state will have the data you need. Also, if in your selector statistic is an array, then statistic.allStatistics is invalid since an array doesn't have an allStatistics property

Comment: Your selector should not be an array because you are selecting your state (which is interface State ), so you should be more like (selectStatisticsState, ((state) : State => state.allStatistics). Now allStatistics is an array. So your get api can return a Statistic object, which has that subarray in it and that (statistic$ | async).allStatistics should work then. A working stackblitz example would be best, but that is probably the root of your problem

Comment: Yes You are right I think , ı am added error image. Thank you very much for your interest and for your help by the way. I changed the code  selectAllStatistics = createSelector(
    selectStatisticsState,
    ((statistic): Statistics => statistic.allStatistics)
);

Comment: @BuğrahanZencir, made an edit to my answer; see if it helps with your createSelector. It also explains the error you got

Comment: When I wrote the selector code you suggested, the IDE did not give an error, but my data does not appear in the table. I edited my latest codes and added the data image from the api to my question. we are very close to solving the problem

Comment: Very hard to tell what the issue may be here, but clearly you are getting the data. Also make sure to update your code snippets to what is the latest situation. Though if you are making and getting the data, one thing that comes to mind is making sure your reducer is actually saving the data correctly to your state. Make sure you are actually having it respond to the correct action that was dispatched. If you can make a stackblitz  which at least shows how your code is laid out it will help a lot; because it is really hard to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: You can also try subscribing to statistics$ in an ngOnInit function, ex: this.statistics$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); and make sure it is actually being updated and returns the correct data you would expect